# How to interpret classification output - Predective model

Tags: classification, predictive-modeling

What is the significance of the macro avg? I'm not sure if this report signifies a good prediction by the model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your model is decent. Predictions are better than random chance.

Macro average is a simple average of the performance measures (precision, recall etc) across all classes/labels.

Micro average is a weighted average of the same , where the weights are based on the number of samples per class/label (support column).